# Dell XPS 13 using libinput, touchpad not tap-clicking on window manager

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, xps, input-devices, libinput

UPDATE: This appears to be an issue with Unity, as GNOME works.

I recently made the following changes which fix the palm detection for the touchpad on my Dell XPS 13. But, when I did so, it now prevents tap-clicking on menu items in applications (the window manager). I can tap-click on anything else though, and press-click works on the window manager menus though. If I remove my changes, tap-clicking works again on the window manager.

Anyone have experience with this?

Here are the changes I've performed. Running Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Install xserver-xorg-input-libinput.
2. Create /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf containing:

   Section "InputClass"

   Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"

   MatchIsTouchpad "on"

   MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

   Driver "libinput"

   Option "Tapping" "True"

   Option "PalmDetection" "True"

   Option "TappingDragLock" "True"

   EndSection

Comment: I have the same problem--did you fix it? Somewhere else I read that you're not supposed to have that libinput package, but there should be one with 'hwe' in the name that is made for your system.

Still, I installed that to no avail. If you have any solutions, I'd like to hear it.

edit: I found that it only happens with the menus integrated in the window decoration. After running gsettings set com.canonical.Unity integrated-menus false, you can simply tap-to-click on the menus. But I don't like the menus in the top bar (especially because it saves no vertical space at all).